# having trouble setting up sms php

Tags: php, sms

I cant seems to send text message using php

this code doesn't work but everything shows up $text['pn'] is the phone number (##########) and $text['pp'] is provider (@myboostmobile.com)

```
$text = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='plmexico'  "));
     $textto = $text['pn'].$text['pp'];
mail($textto, "", "http://www.logamp.com/mobile/vmusic/view.php?id=", "From: notification <not@logamp.com>\r\n");
```

when i  do it this way

```
mail("##########@myboostmobile.com", "", "Your packaged has arrived!", "From: test test <test@test.name>\r\n");
```

it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe,

```
$textto = $text['pn'] . '@' . $text['pp'] . '.com';
```

Verify the contents of `textto`.

**Edit:**
Basically the goal here is, when you have two similar lines of code and only one of them is broken, you have to move the broken line of code slowly closer to other one to pinpoint where the problem really is.

Comment: `$textto = $text['pn'].$text['pp']; echo $textto` ##########@myboostmobile.com

Comment: Maybe the mail server thinks that its spam, considering it's a URL. You should get the bottom one as close to the top one step by step and see what exactly about the top one is broken.

Comment: it didnt work seems like php inside the mail wont work at all

Comment: PHP works fine inside the call to `mail`, it is PHP itself. Walk through the steps you took to get the top and bottom as close as possible in your question details.

Comment: What ended up being the problem?

Comment: its was weird ("Your packaged has arrived!") wont let me change it so i just leave it like that so i could get the text message, I think its because my phone. I had many issues with it.